# react-native-vector-icons Android

Tags: android, react-native

I sucessfully imported icons into iOS and Android by the following:

`npm i --save react-native-vector-icons`

`react-native link`

add: `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"` to build.gradle

However, after closing my Android emulator and returning to the project I am no longer able to view these icons. I've tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` as well as going through the above process but can no longer view these icons on Android (iOS is unaffected and working). I am also starting the emulator before using `react-native run-android`. I've even tried to run the Android emulator after removing the vector icons and I can't get anything to run on Android.

My current error reads:
"A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'."

What am I missing? Why would it work and then after closing and reopening the project, no longer work?
[image]

Part of my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rncardreplacement"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure the issue was that you had gradle 2.2 installed and the project was setup to 1.1.3 like you get in the errors.

For example this is the gradle file of one of my modules:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
```

But this is another module:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
```

Comment: Does that mean I need to downgrade my project gradle or is it posisble to update the module gradle from 1.1.3 to 2.2?

Comment: It would depend mostly on the modules you use. I didn't find any problems and Google actually recommends to use the last version.

Comment: That was it! Sorry for the delay.`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'` is inside react-native-vector-icons and I just changes it to `2.1.0` and it worked. Thank you!